# Automatically Move Focus Between Dialogs

Tags: mfc, modal-dialog, focus, modeless-dialog

I have a modal dialog that shows a modeless 'companion dialog' on a button press. To make the UI more intuitive and fluid I'd like the focus to follow the mouse and move between the dialogs without requiring an extra click.

Is there a simple message handler that would help here? I think I could do it by using `TrackMouseEvent` and `OnMouseHover` in each dialog - but that seems pretty involved for such a 'simple' effect?

Answer (score 0):

OK...so I was totally over thinking this! Just use `OnMouseMove` and `OnNcMouseMove`:

```cpp
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void DlgA::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    HWND hwnd = ::GetActiveWindow();
    if (pDlgB != NULL)
    {
        if (hwnd == pDlgB->GetSafeHwnd())
        {
            // Make the focus switch automatically
            SetFocus();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [How to set focus in a dialog box](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040802-00/?p=38283).

Comment: Though, even when done properly, this will start a taskbar flash blizzard if you ever decide to switch to a different thread, e.g. a different application's window.

Comment: @IInspectable - I don't see why it would? It only switches focus from one to the other if one (or other) already has the focus. If the focus is elsewhere, it won't do anything.